# Deleting a negative value from number input and validation

Tags: html, validation

I feel that this is a dumb question, sorry.

I have an input with the `number` type and I want to add some validation to it. It is not required, so an empty string should be valid, negative numbers too, but not the `-` sign.

Consider now I've entered `-102` into that field and removing symbols one by one, watching for changes.

Here's the basic [codepen](https://codepen.io/k-one-o-two/pen/WNdwbWJ) for it. As you can see, when there's just a `-` sign left the value (`event.target.value`) is an smpty string, which should be valid.

So, how can I check if there is only a minus sign left and mark this field as invalid?

```js
const el = document.getElementById('input');

el.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
  const value = e.target.value;
  console.log(value)
})
```

```html
<input type="number" id="input">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `pattern` to only accept positive or negative number

in JS you can call method `checkValidity()` or use `{yourinput}.validity.valid` to check if value entered in input is valid or not

in css you can use the pseudo class `:invalid` to design your input when value entered don't match the pattern/field expectation

```js
const el = document.getElementById('input');

el.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
  console.log(el.checkValidity());
  if (!el.checkValidity()) {
    //treat case input invalid
  }
})
```

```css
input:invalid {
 color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="input" pattern="\d+">
```

Comment: but I need negative numbers to be valid, I've mentioned it

Comment: a ok i didnt get it. in that case only use the pattern to ask a number (negative or positive) if only minux signe is use it will be invalid

Comment: I edit my reply with this information